# How to fix an iPhone with half a screen showing a different color?

Tags: screen, iphone

I have an iPhone 6. It screen was changed about 10 months ago and its battery was changed about 1.5 months ago. Yesterday, I suddenly noticed that half of the screen is darkened and with yellow-ish vertical lines. As far as I can tell, there was no immediate damage that was connected to this (i.e., no drops, or water damage, etc).

This appears to be a hardware issue and I don't know if it is related to either of the fixes.

Here is an attempt at a screenshot (which is taken from my macbook):

[image: Half discolored screen]

Does anyone have an idea what this problem is and is there an easy way to fix this? Do I need to purchase another screen?

I don't live in North America, so getting a screen replaced will cost more than $200USD, so I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Hardware issue. Try a full erase & restore (backup to iTunes first) but when it comes back looking like this, you'll confirm the hardware glitch for sure.

Comment: Thanks. Probably hardware, but I will try that to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also try a full factory reset, like IconDaemon suggests. If that doesn't improve your situation, you have the following choices:

1. Go to an official Apple store or a premium service provider to exchange your screen (this will cost you between 100 and 300$ depending on your location)
2. Go to an iPhone doctor or clinic which replaces the screen with a cheap aftermarket china one (Be very careful with this, most of the screens have a very bad quality and you can't get support from Apple afterwards. To check, if a screen is genuine, there should be no yellow glare and you can press firmly on the glass without damaging the display)
3. Buy a broken iPhone online and change the screen yourself as this tutorial on ifixit states: [iFixit - iPhone 6 Repair](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+6+Displayeinheit+mit+Home+Button+und+Frontkamera/29339)

Comment: Forgot to accept your question earlier. In the end, I had to get the screen replaced again. Where I was living, there are no iPhone stores nearby, so I needed to get an aftermarket (cheapo) screen installed. It was about $220USD for the service.