# iPhone X has a green line on the left of screen. How to fix it?

Tags: iphone, hardware, screen

My friend got this iPhone X and it suddenly has a bright green line on the left side of the screen. Whole display getting bit greenish because of it. The warranty is also finished because it's more than a year and a half he bought it. It happened suddenly because he is assuring nothing happened like dropping it or any kind of water damage. He tried to reset it but the result is the same. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Apple.SE! [Vertical lines on left side of iPhone 4s after it fell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360415/vertical-lines-on-the-left-side-of-iphone-4s-after-it-fell-down-can-it-be-fixed) and [half iphone screen showing diff colour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282370/how-to-fix-an-iphone-with-half-a-screen-showing-a-different-color) These are questions on this site which recommend replacement. The first step to seclude software is to erase and restore from backup. If persists, it can be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually comes together with issues with touch response for which there is a replacement program by Apple in which the display would be replaced free of charge outside of the regular warranty period. (https://support.apple.com/iphone-x-display-module-replacement-program)

Visit your local Apple Store or Service Provider and check to see if it can be fixed under this program.