# iPhone has an illuminated line on the right edge of my screen, all the time I use it

Tags: screen

Can I get my iPhone fixed easily?  Will I need anew screen - expensive!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Please provide infos such as: What have you tried and how didn't it work? What is your iPhone model and what iOS update is it running? etc.

Comment: Related:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365717/119271. What specific model iPhone?  This is not a software issue or something that can be fixed with an update; it's hardware related.  Can you post an image?